# Run .bat within html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a small project which allow to run .bat in html itself and below coding is working for me.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<center>
<select name="menu" id="menu">
  <option>Select Printer</option>
<option value="file:\\10.50.100.212\location\run1.bat">option1</option>
<option value="file:\\10.50.100.212\location\run2.bat">option2</option>
</select>
<button id="btn">Go!</button>
</center>
<script>
var urlmenu = document.getElementById('menu');
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

// Set up a click event handling function for the button 
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Confirmation of action for testing
  console.log("Navigating to:" + urlmenu.value);

  // Open new window with correct URL
  window.open( urlmenu.value );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but in above solution .bat file use to download and we have to open it in order to run the script.

**Is it possible to run .bat without downloading, any suggestion with php or without appreciated.**

Comment: If you want to run a system file (.bat, .sh, .exe etc.) you need to a server which installed on your system.

Comment: I do have a server, kindly advice me how to utilize

Comment: You can use XHR call for activate system files from html. Create service like http://localhost:8080/REST/runMyCommand then call this url from client (with using Javascript XHR)

Comment: I did search about XHR and I did not found any example, If possible can you explain what you mentioned with "localhost:8080/REST/runMyCommand " and how to call using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run any executable in JS, because you are in a client sandbox. You could do it on server side, if the server is on the same maschine as your client. Then open the php side that executes your `.bat`.

You have to run the PHP server (Apache or others) on your client machine.

Comment: how .php code should looks like, and how to link with my code. any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this steps for do that.

**Create a server.**

You can use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html).

**Write a service which is run batch files. (test.php)**

```
$fileName = $_GET['fileName'];
//C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.bat
exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START . $fileName .');
```

Call this service from client.

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/test.php?fileName=C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.bat");
oReq.send();
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply and I have installed XAMPP and tried some simple code "echo exec('whoami');" which is working got respond as "nt authority\system" but when I'm trying test.php as you mentioned, I am getting no response, Please advice